# cmake add_subdirectory with other cmake filename than CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

CMake documentation states that when *add_subdirectory* is executed cmake looks for CMakeLists.txt in the directory. Is there any way to change the name of makefile? For example, if I have two cmake files for two completely different configurations and don't want to mix everything in one.

Of course I can create CMakeLists.txt and include something else in it depending on configuration, but I'm just curious if it's possible to make *add_subdirectory* look for  make file with arbitrary name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. The file name `CMakeLists.txt` is unconfigurably hard-coded in CMake itself. Your best option is, as you say, create a "signpost" `CMakeLists.txt` file which will just `include()` the real content based on whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I'll answer anyway in case it helps someone. Per the book "Professional CMake" 3rd edition, you should use

include(fileName [OPTIONAL] [RESULT_VARIABLE myVar] [NO_POLICY_SCOPE])

"include() expects the name of a file to read in, whereas add_subdirectory() expects a directory and will look for a CMakeLists.txt file within that directory. The file name passed to include() typically has the extension .cmake, but it can be anything." pg 56.

There are other differences between add_subdirectory() and include() to be mindful of so I would suggest getting the book and giving it a read.